# Does Karate Framework support Gatling-Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, karate

with [Gatling supporting Kotlin since 3.7](https://gatling.io/2021/11/gatling-3-7-java-dsl-kotlin-and-much-more/), does Karate support writing Gatling using Kotlin? The examples from Karate Framework are all geared towards using Scala.

Sample project from Gatling [here](https://github.com/gatling/gatling-gradle-plugin-demo-kotlin/blob/main/src/gatling/kotlin/computerdatabase/ComputerDatabaseSimulation.kt)

My brief research seem to suggest it is not possible to mix and match Scala + Kotlin https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/mixing-kotlin-and-non-java-jvm-languages/222

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gatling in Java and Kotlin was only recently made possible. We certainly plan to add support for writing Karate-Gatling tests in Java and Kotlin, and we would start with Java. This is not a priority though. My suggestion is if you can contribute and at least do some investigation, that will help. The existing Scala adapter that Karate uses to bridge Gatling is very few lines of code.